# parse.com : Inner query on an id column Not retrieving all columns I want

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Parse class Schema :

Class name : balance

Columns : myid createdAt amount

Class name : tokens

Columns : myid registerUser isActiveToken

I want to retrieve amount, myid, registerUser, isActiveToken using parse.com javascript.

I am not able to get this using parse js refernce.

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries

> matchesKeyInQuery is giving a toJSOn error in parse js

```
var balance = Parse.Object.extend("balance");
var teamQuery = new Parse.Query(balance);
var userQuery = new Parse.Query("tokens");
userQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("amount", teamQuery); //I made a blunder here by not understanding matchesKeyInQuery
userQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
        // results has the list of users with a hometown team with a winning record
    }
});
```

> matchesQuery is throwing a bad inner query error

```
var balance = Parse.Object.extend("balance");
    var tokens = Parse.Object.extend("tokens");
    var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(balance);
    innerQuery.exists("amount");
    var query = new Parse.Query(tokens);
    query.matchesQuery("myid", innerQuery);
    query.find({
        success: function(comments) {
            // tokens now contains the tokens for balance with amounts.
        }
    });
```

Overcame this through javascript merging(dirty way), would love to find something in Parse SDK

Comment: post your query and more details about the collection structure.

Comment: @NikolayRusev Reformatted my question to show better. I have included how my classes look like. My query is not at all working and the one in above parse.com example.

Comment: where is your query?

Comment: Added query @NikolayRusev

Comment: I am looking for something that is like a JOIN in SQL on myid column

Answer (score 0):

in the first query method `matchesKeyInQuery` accepts 3 arguments, first one is the key in the called query, the second one argument is the key in the passed query and third one is the passed query.

```
    var balance = Parse.Object.extend("balance");
    var tokens = Parse.Object.extend("tokens");
    var teamQuery = new Parse.Query(balance);
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(tokens);
    userQuery.equalTo("myId",12); //sample
    userQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("myId","myId", teamQuery);
    userQuery.find({
        success: function(results) {
            // results has the list of users with a hometown team with a winning record
        }
    });
```

for the second query, you should have relation between two collections . and you can use `matchesQuery` method.

Comment: This does not give me 'amount' column( My ultimate target) from balance class. It is only giving myid, registerUser, isActiveToken from tokens class.

Comment: i don't know how they are related. My answer is only to tell you how to use parse queries. if you want balance and tokens to be related see parse.com relational data - https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-relational-data and query's include method !

Comment: They are one- to - One on tokenId. Does that help you answer

Comment: what type is tokenId?